# Find condition on signed matrix $A$ such that $\sum_jA_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq 0$ implies $\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq 0$?

Tags: matrices, positivity

As stated in the title, My question is:

Suppose $\sum_jA_{ij}\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0,\forall i\in[n]$.

How to find condition on symmetric, diagonal-free, signed matrix $A$ ($A_{ij}=+1$ or $-1$ if $i\neq j$) such that $$\sum_jA_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq 0,\forall i\in[n]$$ implies $$\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq 0,\forall i\in[n]$$ where the region of $\theta_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $\forall i\in[n]$.

I came up with this question in my research, but I don't know whether there is a way to proceed.

Comment: May the condition depend on $\theta$, or do you look for a condition which works for all $\theta$ such that for all $i$, $\sum_j A_{i,j} \sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Hi. the claim (the first inequality implies the second one) doesn't hold for any $\theta$, thus maybe adding constraint can help. The $\theta$ I considered actually satisfy the condition $\sum_j A_{ij}\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0,\forall i$.

Comment: You do not answer my question. I had already noticed the condition on theta. Do you wish a condition on $A$ which works for all $\theta$ satisfying this condition ?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes, I need it works for all $\theta$ satisfying $\sum_jA_{ij}\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0,\forall i$.